# Segmentation basis sum of a column called "Value"

Tags: sql-server-2005

There is a column called Value where in we need to find out the sum(over column Value) of all say 15ooo rows.
 Then we need to divide/segment the complete data in 3 parts, that is if the sum is say 300 then each bucket should have 100 as total sum of column Value.

Also, first we need to arrainge the column in descending order.

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Google "Bin packing SQL Server"

Comment: It does sound like a bin packing issue, but if you want us to help code it then post sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Were going to need some additional detail.

As mentioned, it sounds like a bin packing problem. A great article is here, please let us know if it helps:
[link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2008/08/12/How-to-sum-up-an-unknown-number-of-records.aspx)

Comment: thats fine but then i need to comapare when in data set reaches the value equal to one third  of data set .. that would first bucket and so on ...

Comment: we might need to use cursor to compare the cumulative result, row by row